# How to add class while selected options goes to more than one line?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have used [select2]: https://select2.org/ plugin for mutliple select in my  web site where i can select multiple options.
And here my question is if selected options goes more then one line i have to add class to the input.

[image]

here is my html code in Blade file,

```
<select name="certification[]" id="certification" class="multiple-select-box" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Certification">
    @foreach($school_certification as $certificate)
    <option value="{{$certificate->certification_name}}">{{$certificate->certification_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Here is javascript code of initialization of select2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.multiple-select-box').select2({
    width: "100%",
});
</script>
```

Please help i am totally stuck into this.
Thank you.

Comment: off the top of my head you could, on option select check the height of the select (or whatever container select2 is adding the option to) and if it greater than height of 1 row add the class

Comment: I have checked with this but not getting success its not giving accuracy.

Comment: can you make a fiddle or provide a link?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis thanks. Got solution from this comment.